# Using collections to insert records in oracle table containing a virtual column

Tags: arrays, oracle, plsql

I intend to insert around 5 million records into a table and hence decided to use collections. The table has 300+ columns out of which one is a virtual column, say col2.

I have got the code working but got a few **Q**ueries. Any pointer will be a great help.

```
01 DECLARE
02   TYPE test IS TABLE OF SAMPLE_TBL%ROWTYPE;
03   l_tab test := test();            
04   BEGIN
05     l_tab.extend;
07     l_tab(l_tab.last).col1   := 1;
08     -- l_tab(l_tab.last).col2:= 1; VIRTUAL col
09     l_tab(l_tab.last).col3   := 1; 
10     ..
11     l_tab(l_tab.last).col300 := 1;
12   
13     FORALL i IN l_tab.first .. l_tab.last
17       INSERT INTO SAMPLE_TBL(
18         col1,
19         -- col2,
20         col3,
21         --
22       col300  
23     ) VALUES (
24       l_tab(i).col1,
25       -- l_tab(i).col2,
26       l_tab(i).col3,
27       --
28       l_tab(i).col300
29     );
30     COMMIT;
31   END;
32 /
```

**Q.** Since col2 is virtual, I have to prepare the insert statement using column names (lines 18-22).The code looks real messy as I have to do for 300+ cols. *Is there any way possible to exlude the virtual column but still use something like* `INSERT INTO SAMPLE_TBL values(val1,val3,..,val300);`

**Q.** From lines 07-11, values are assigned using actual column names, like so, `l_tab(l_tab.last).col1 := 1;` So, is there any way to tell the insert statement (or any other functionality) to insert l_tab(l_tab.last).**col1** into **col1**, without having to write the column names(lines 24-28) in sequence all over again - something like mapping a hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE sample_tbl
(col1 number,
 col2 AS (col1+1),
 col3 number,
 col4 number,
 col5 number);
```

Create a view without the virtual column:

```
CREATE VIEW v_sample_tbl AS
SELECT col1, col3, col4, col5 FROM sample_tbl;
```

Inserting in the table fails:

```
DECLARE
  TYPE test IS TABLE OF SAMPLE_TBL%ROWTYPE;
  l_tab test := test();            
  BEGIN
    l_tab.extend;
    l_tab(l_tab.last).col1 := 1;
    l_tab(l_tab.last).col3 := 1; 
    l_tab(l_tab.last).col4 := 1; 
    l_tab(l_tab.last).col5 := 1;

    FORALL i IN l_tab.first .. l_tab.last
      INSERT INTO sample_tbl VALUES l_tab(i);
      COMMIT;
  END;
/


ERROR at line 1:
ORA-54013: INSERT operation disallowed on virtual columns
ORA-06512: at line 11
```

Insert on the View works:

```
DECLARE
  TYPE test IS TABLE OF v_sample_tbl%ROWTYPE;
  l_tab test := test();            
  BEGIN
    l_tab.extend;
    l_tab(l_tab.last).col1 := 1;
    l_tab(l_tab.last).col3 := 1; 
    l_tab(l_tab.last).col4 := 1; 
    l_tab(l_tab.last).col5 := 1;

    FORALL i IN l_tab.first .. l_tab.last
      INSERT INTO v_sample_tbl VALUES l_tab(i);
      COMMIT;
  END;
/   

SQL> select * from sample_tbl;

      COL1       COL2       COL3       COL4       COL5
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          2          1          1          1
```

Comment: I tried to use the construct VALUES l_tab(i). I am getting the error: ORA-54013: INSERT operation disallowed on virtual columns. I am sure I have not set any value corresponding to virtual col.

Comment: Are you inserting on the view (without the virtual col)?

Comment: Haven't tried the view approach yet. I tried to insert into the table itself

Comment: You can't use the question2 solution without the first one, as cols should match.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 'cols should match' - this is where I am confused. We have named attributes like l_tab(i).colN and it should match to colN irrespective of the sequence of columns. What am I missing ? Excuse me if the queries are too basic.

Comment: you should have the same number of cols and same order, to be able to do INSERT INTO sample_tbl VALUES l_tab(i); , as sample_tbl has the virtual col, it fails, so you need to INSERT INTO a view without that virtual col.